# Problem installing Hotfix CM_2013.1.0.87899

Tags: 2013-sp1

We have a temporary problem on our system with the license on a new Tridion 2013 SP1 installation. The error we receive is:

> Can not continue due to license violation. The number of named users in your system (1) exceeds the limit specified in the license: 1.

I saw this is a known issue and until we get the proper license, I wanted to quickly fix this with Hotfix 87411. 
I downloaded the cummulative hotfix 87899 (that includes 87411) from SDL Tridion World and in `readme.txt` it says:

Remove the file `Tridion.ContentManager.dll` located in the `%WINDIR%\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Tridion.ContentManager\7.1.0.1290__360aac4d3354074b` folder

However, I cannot find `Tridion.ContentManager.dll` anywhere in GAC.

Does anybody know how to apply this hotfix? 
Note that we cannot install the whole HR1 yet due to some other issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you report this issue in the hotfix readme to customer support?

Comment: @Bart Koopman, I created a ticket for SDL saying the same thing under client's account. Let me know if that is what you meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably be looking at wrong path of GAC. Can you try finding the DLL at below path:

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL
```

or

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64
```